# How to prove intersection of two non-equal singleton sets is empty

Tags: coq

I've boiled down the meat of a proof to a few statements that the intersection of two distinct singleton sets are empty, but am not able to prove this seemingly simple fact.

I've looked through the library of Ensembles, Powerset Facts, Constructive Sets and the like, but haven't been able to find anything that turns out to be useful.

```
Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.

Example x: string := "x".
Example y: string := "y".

Lemma ex:
Intersection string (Singleton string x)
  (Singleton string y) = Empty_set string.
Proof.
  ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the extensionality axiom:

```
Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.

Example x: string := "x".
Example y: string := "y".

Lemma ex:
Intersection string (Singleton string x)
  (Singleton string y) = Empty_set string.
Proof.
apply Extensionality_Ensembles. split.
- intros _ [b Ha Hb].
  inversion Ha. inversion Hb. unfold x, y in *. congruence.
- now intros _ [].
Qed.
```